# How to get Helpers back into needed context in BlogEngine.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, blogengine.net

Trying to integrate BlogEngine.NET into an existing large and complicated .NET web site, I've found that my cshtml files cannot locate the helpers files. This is a site which has not previously made any use of MVC, and my own experience with MVC is modest enough that I had to review to even remind myself what helpers were.

I placed the BlogEngine.NET code in its own subdirectory.

Now the code in "**[rootdirectory]/Blogs/default.cshtml**" needs access to the code which now resides in the "**[rootdirectory]/App_Code/Helpers/**" directory.

I haven't changed the code trying to do this, ad representative sample of which looks like: "**@Helpers.ExtensionsHelper.GetExtensions(true)**".

I've tried moving the Helpers directory and its contents around extensively. I've tried adding assemblies to the web site to include all the assemblies that appear in BlogEngine.NET.

I always wind up with the error, "**The name 'Helpers' does not exist in the current context**".

Comment: Could you clarify why you are using MVC helpers?  If your current site is built on webforms and BlogEngine.net is a webforms project it seems like using MVC is making the project more complicated.

Comment: Using MVC helpers was entirely BlogEngine's idea. Until BlogEngine demanded it, our web site made no use of MVC.I finally fumbled around and got something to work, but I really don't know what I got right.